# Expand and collapse using javascript with [+] and [-]

Tags: javascript

The following is the code i am using for expanding and collapsing my div.
Now I want to make little changes to the code.
When I Expand the div,A "[-]" with div content and when I collapse a "[+]" with div content should come.

```
<style type="text/css">
.gap
{

 border:1px solid black

}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e =document.getElementById(id);

       if(e.style.display == 'none')
        {
          e.style.display = 'block';
          col.innerHTML=valu;
        }
       else
       {
          e.style.display = 'none';

       }
    }

    function edit(id,item)
    {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       var f = document.getElementById(item);

     document.getElementById('id4').innerHTML=e.innerHTML;     
      e.innerHTML=f.innerHTML;
      window.location=window.location;

    }
    function cancel(id,item)
    {

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=document.getElementById(item).innerHTML;
    }

</script>

<div class="gap" ><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id1');" id="x">[+]<div id="click" style="float:right;">Click here</div></a></div>

<div id="id1" style="display:none;">This is foo</div>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('id2');" ><div class="gap">click here1</div></a>

<div id="id2" style="display:none;">click here1
<div> <a href="#"  onclick="edit('id2','id3');">Edit</a></div>
</div>




<div id="id3" style="display:none;">Edit
<div> <a href="#"  onclick="cancel('id2','id4')">cancel</a></div>
</div>


<div id="id4" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I am Waiting Fotr your help.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying that when you try to make these changes, you get some sort of error? If so -- what is the error? Or are you saying that you haven't tried to make these changes, and are hoping that someone here will graciously make them for you? Or . . . ?

Comment: Please put your working code, that you mentioned, in your question so people can look at it an tell you how to add [+] and [-] signs.

Comment: Original fiddle for anyone who wishes to take a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/kDYtU/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you want?

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e =document.getElementById(id);
   var label = document.getElementById("x");

   if(e.style.display == 'none')
    {
      label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("[+]","[-]");
      e.style.display = 'block';
      col.innerHTML=valu;
    }
   else
   {
      label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace("[-]","[+]");
      e.style.display = 'none';

   }
}
```

Comment: @leonhart..This will work only for one div..I am using the several divs with different names..

Comment: @leonhart... I need to display the contents as well..like [+]click here...[+] click here1 etc..I mam using several divs.

Comment: @leonhart...Thanks..The code you have given is worked for me..Thanks you for your valuable time..

Answer (score 0):

use the show and hide functions of javascript to show and hide the divs:

```
<div id="showHide" class="open" style="display: block;" onclick="showHide();">
    <!-- Your Contents -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showHide(currentElem) {
    if (currentElem.ClassName.indexOf('open') > -1) {
        // This means its open, now close it
        currentElem.className = 'closed';
        currentElem.style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
        currentElem.className = 'open';
        currentElem.style.display = 'block';  
    }
}
```

Comment: @ruakh..You are right..I have tried but I am not yet success..Please let me know the code to do it..

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('x').innerText = '[-]';
        e.style.display = 'block';
        //col.innerHTML = valu;
    }
    else {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('x').innerText = '[+]';
    }
}
```

When you click the [+] on the div this code shows the div and changes the [+] to [-] and vice versa. if you want to change the [+] to something else? like '[+]click here' you can just change the corresponding string in the code. I do not understand what do you mean by 'you want to change the content also..'. What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: `innerText` doesn't work in Firefox. Also, `textContent` doesn't work in IE.

Comment: i guess the op can replace innerText by innerHTML without sacrificing functionality here

Comment: @codetantrik..This One I have tried and will work..But I need to display the contents as well..like [+]click here...[+] click here1 etc..I mam using several divs..